# Binding disappears on simple user control

Tags: wpf, data-binding, user-controls

I have a simple usercontrol with a single DependencyProperty. I am unable to set bindings on this property. I don't get any exceptions but the bindings just disappear.

I cannot begin to see what is going wrong here. It's so simple.

Here's my usercontrol:

XAML:

```
<UserControl x:Class="Test.Controls.SimpleUserControl"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         x:Name="ucThis">
        <TextBox Text="{Binding Path=MyString, ElementName=ucThis}" />
</UserControl>
```

Code:

```
public partial class SimpleUserControl : UserControl
{
    public SimpleUserControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    public string MyString
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(MyStringProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MyStringProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty MyStringProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("MyString", typeof(string),
        typeof(SimpleUserControl), new UIPropertyMetadata("simple user control"));
}
```

XAML from a test app:

```
    <StackPanel>
        <testControls:SimpleUserControl MyString="{Binding Path=TestString}"
                                         x:Name="simpleUC" />

        <Label Content="From control" />
        <Border Margin="5"
                BorderBrush="Black"
                BorderThickness="1"
                Visibility="{Binding Path=MyString, ElementName=simpleUC, Converter={StaticResource nullVisConv}}">
            <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Path=MyString, ElementName=simpleUC}" />
        </Border>
        <TextBlock Text="Value from control is null."
                   Margin="5"
                   Visibility="{Binding Path=MyString, ElementName=simpleUC, Converter={StaticResource nullVisConv}, ConverterParameter={custom:BooleanValue Value=True}}" />

        <Label Content="From binding" />
        <Border Margin="5"
                BorderBrush="Black"
                BorderThickness="1"
                Visibility="{Binding Path=TestString, Converter={StaticResource nullVisConv}}">
            <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding Path=TestString}" />
        </Border>
        <TextBlock Text="Value from binding is null."
                   Margin="5"
                   Visibility="{Binding Path=TestString, Converter={StaticResource nullVisConv}, ConverterParameter={custom:BooleanValue Value=True}}" />

        <TextBox Text="You can set focus here." />
    </StackPanel>
```

The main window for the test app has a property named `TestString`, is its own DataContext and implements `INotifyPropertyChanged` correctly. `SimpleUserControl.MyString` updates as it should but the property it is bound to (`TestString`) does not. I have inspected this with Snoop; the binding I set on the `SimplerUserControl` is just not present at run time. What is happening here?

**UPDATE**
Okay. So if I specify `Mode=TwoWay` the binding works. That's great. Can anyone explain to me why it behaves this way?
Thanks.

Comment: It's `Mode=TwoWay`. Damn.

Comment: Great you found it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working as designed :). DPs default to 1-way. Personally, I would change your DependencyProperty.Register() call to make the DP default to two-way. That way you don't have to specify two-way explicitly every time you use it. You'll notice that the framework typically makes DPs two-way by default when you'd want the property to write back. Just a convienience.

Comment: Is there anyway to specify something other than TwoWay as the default?

Answer (score 0):

Yes you need to provide TwoWay Mode for Dependency Property:

```
 public string MyString
    {
        get { return (string)GetValue(MyStringProperty); }
        set { SetValue(MyStringProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty MyStringProperty =
 DependencyProperty.Register("MyString", typeof(string),
 typeof(UserControl1), new FrameworkPropertyMetadata("simple user control", FrameworkPropertyMetadataOptions.BindsTwoWayByDefault));
```